# Redirect the page from another page url come from database and bind in div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want Redirect the page  from clicking div tag but it can redirect div is fill from Database. How can make it can be redirect by clicking the div.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlHelp.CNSTR = con;
    DisplayMenuList();                  
}

protected void DisplayMenuList()
{
    DataTable dtMenuList = new DataTable();
    string strSql = "select * from ModuleMaster where IsActive='Y' order by ModuleName asc";
    string appendHtml = string.Empty;
    dtMenuList = SqlHelper.SqlHelper.ReturnDataTable(strSql);
    if (dtMenuList != null && dtMenuList.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dtMenuList.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            appendHtml += "<div class='verticallyCenter' style='width: 20%; float: left;display:block;'><a href='/Admin/" + Convert.ToString(dtMenuList.Rows[i]["ModuleUrl"]);
            appendHtml += "'><input type='image' name='" + Convert.ToString(dtMenuList.Rows[i]["ModuleName"]);
            appendHtml += "' id='" + Convert.ToString(dtMenuList.Rows[i]["ModuleName"]);
            appendHtml += "' src='../" + Convert.ToString(dtMenuList.Rows[i]["ImageUrl"]) + "' class='MenuButtons'/></a>";
            {
                appendHtml += "<span class='MenuNotification'>" + i + "</span>";
            }
            appendHtml += "</div>";  
       }
    }
    divMenuList.InnerHtml = appendHtml;
    appendHtml = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: what is the real issue here ? - how your html is rendered ? From what I see you have two inputs for redirect, one anchor and one image button - what is not working ?

Comment: anchor html tag not working.

Comment: Hi sir please help me out..

Comment: place the anchor before the div, and remove the input button for the image

Comment: How can placed.

Comment: string s = "<a href='/Admin/" + Convert.ToString(dtMenuList.Rows[i]["ModuleUrl"]);
s = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;

Comment: use this but it is not working